# Got rid of alpha channel containing colors

Tags: gimp

I try to edit some UV map exported from Blender.
Before I want to edit some textures I want to select the regions by alpha.

What I did was some kind of binarization of the image and got rid of the false pixels.

That is working so far I got a black background and a white foreground.

My problem is I did something wrong and now all pixels are fully transparent.
So if I deselect the alpha channel I can see the regions I want to select.
If I remove the alpha channel everything is white.
What I want is a transparent background and only the regions of the UV map visible (alpha value 255).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you call "100% alpha"? Fully opaque? And "deselecting the alpha channel" is really clicking on its visibility in the Channels list?

Comment: What is a false pixel? What is binarization? You really need to land your question. An image as an example would be useful.